# Is there a way to tell Capistrano to deploy a Local Repository to a Remote Server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

I'm having a bit trouble while using capistrano, What I need to do is **deploy from a Repository which resides in my local machine to my private VPS**

So far my **deploy.rb** file looks like this:

```
set :application, "store"
set :repository,  "/home/jose/linode/store"
#set :local_repository, "/home/jose/linode/store"
set :branch, "master"
set :scm, :git
set :user, "root"
set :scm_username, "my_git_user"

set :use_sudo, false

set :deploy_to, '/home/www/store'

# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

role :web, "169.255.255.255"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "169.255.255.255"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "169.255.255.255", :primary => true        # This is where Rails migrations will run
#role :db,  "your slave db-server here"
```

However, this is failing, it's outputting the following error:

**** [169.255.255.255 :: err] fatal: repository '/home/jose/linode/store' does not exist**

This leads me to believe that it's **looking for the repository in the remote server!**

What configuration is needed to tell Capistrano that the Repo is located right here, not on: 169.255.255.255?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting that you are looking for is:

`set :deploy_via, :copy`

That creates a local `.tar.gz` file in your `/tmp/` directory and pushes that to the server during deployment.

If you look at the source code, specifically `lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/strategy/copy.rb`, you'll see a large block of comments beginning with the following.

> ```
>   # This class implements the strategy for deployments which work
>   # by preparing the source code locally, compressing it, copying the
>   # file to each target host, and uncompressing it to the deployment
>   # directory.
> ```

[This article](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2008/5/2/capistrano-2-3-0) was written for an older version, but it's still quite interesting and covers deployment options and optimizations.

Comment: Very interesting! However here: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Significant-Configuration-Variables, which I'm assuming is for the latest version, I don't see the :deploy_via option anymore? Will that be a problem? is there an alternative that you know of? Oh, And Thanks for your reply !

Comment: It could be outdated, but the Capistrano docs have always been notoriously terrible. `deploy_via` is still in the code as far as I can tell, so try it and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for that one. I did notice that myself, since deploy_via, as you said presented no problems.